# Not authorized to access scope - Amazon Advertising API

Tags: java, api, amazon-advertising-api

My purpose is to download the advertising report using existing application details such as AMAZON_CLIENT_ID, AMAZON_CLIENT_SECRET & Access tokens to other java application.

I was able to get the new access token using AMAZON_CLIENT_ID, AMAZON_CLIENT_SECRET & refresh_token. Below is the code to fetch a new access token.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
 Response response;
            MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=" + refreshToken + "&client_id=" + amzClientId + "&client_secret=" + amzClientSceret);
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(“https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token”)
                    .post(body)
                    .addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                    .build();
        response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

After sending the api request to fetch the campaign level stats data,  is gives the following error

```
{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","
details":"Not authorized to access scope XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX","
requestId":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx"}"
```

My question here is, Can I use the same existing AMAZON_CLIENT_ID, AMAZON_CLIENT_SECRET & Access tokens to fetch stats to different java applications(without using login with amazon)?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: Struggling with this myself right now.
From the docs, it looks like you first have to get a profile id from the profiles endpoint.  But that isn't working for me.

Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the access token and client ID for subsequent requests.

.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token)

.addHeader("Amazon-Advertising-API-ClientId", client_id)